# Установка WINE на Solus OS

Tags: linux, wine, solus

Как установить Wine на новую версию Solus OS?
Добавить репозиторий не получается.

Answer (score 2):

В стандартном репозитории wine должен быть, проверьте:

```
apt search wine
```

Ну если нет, то в [wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) есть инструкция по установке.